Azure sphere Send data between 2 azure device(Client to Server) using TCP
I have tried using the PrivateNetworkServices sample from Github to receive data from my PC using Ethernet and it worked. I have set "eth0" as network interface but it always shows wlan0 as DHCPclient. I dont know why. But its working with ethernet.
https://github.com/Azure/azure-sphere-samples/tree/main/Samples/PrivateNetworkServices


I used the above Server code in my azure device 1 and put Client code in 2nd azure device.
Now I am trying to Send data from a Azure sphere Starter kit device to another starter kit. I used the Client code provided in this link to send data.
Unable to use Azure Sphere device as TCP Client
I have added  192.168.100.9 to my client device and Set 192.168.100.10 to my server device.
I have put destination IP 192.168.100.9 is app_manifest.json on Client device using 11000 port on both devices. Still I cant make the connection between these devices.
Please let me know what could be causing the problem. Thank you.

could tell what do want to achieve

I am trying to send data from 1 Azure device with Client code to another Azure device with Server code. I have tried the code mentioned on above link. But can't make the connection from client device to server device.
